# how to store input values into data base?

Tags: jsp, jdbc

```
   `<table>
    <tr><td>TextBox1</td><td><input type="text" name="student1">
      <tr><td>TextBox2</td><td><input type="text" name="student1">
     <tr><td>TextBox3</td><td><input type="text" name="student1">
     <tr><td>TextBox4</td><td><input type="text" name="student1">
       <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </table>`
```

My Problem is that how can i forward those input boxes to another page and how to insert those values into data base?

Comment: but my requirement is like that only ..

Comment: <table>
 <tr>
<td>
        Student Name:</td><td> <input type="text" name="studentname" id="name1" /></td>
        
  <td>Student    ID: </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="studentid" id="name1" /></td>
 
  <td>   Contact   Number:</td>
  <td> <input type="text" name="studentcontact" id="name1" /></td>
  <td>
        Course Name</td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="coursename" id="name1"/>
        </td>
        </tr>
</table>
    </div>
     <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Another Student" />
        <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="remove name" />

Answer (score 0):

the name attribute will need to be unique, otherwise in the above case will just pick the last textbox i.e. 4.

not all too familar with jsp and jdbc but the steps you need to do are the following.

1. change name attribute to be unique.
2. Initialize the class with the specific driver
3. Create a connection object
4. Create statement
5. Execute query
6. Close the connection

Answer (score 0):

You need to engulf the table in a <form> element. A form element allows you to pass data from one page to another. The form can pass parameters in 2 ways GET and POST. The only difference between them is that GET parameters pass are visible in the URL where are POST parameters are passed by the browser internally.

Having said that, your page should look like:

```
`<form action='MyPage.jsp' method='POST'>
  <table>
   <tr><td>TextBox1</td><td><input type="text" name="student1"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>TextBox2</td><td><input type="text" name="student2"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>TextBox3</td><td><input type="text" name="student3"></td></tr>
   <tr><td>TextBox4</td><td><input type="text" name="student4"></td></tr>
   <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
  </table>
 </form>`
```

Now you create a page called MyPage.jsp, read the parameters and insert them in the DB.

I hope this helps you.